# Aprilia Pegaso not starting

Tags: motorcycle, aprilia

My Aprilia Pegaso 650 has suddendly decided, a few days ago, not start anymore. I'm trying to figure out the problem, but I'm short of a tech manual and tools, too, so I'm a little impaired here.

The evidence: the power button has no effect, it's like it's not even pressed. No click from the rele, no usual micro dimming of the lights on the dashboard, nothing.

The battery is fine (just recharged) and the bike was fine till a few days ago, it's not an old unused one. I already opened the power button case, but everything seems fine there. I can get myself a multimeter, no problem, but I'd have no idea where to use it and working on the sidewalk is not that I can disassemble everything and follow the wires :-\

The model is the Tuscany Tibet from 2003, has anyone any hint/idea on how to check what's going on?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: "No click from the relay" - so step 1, make sure there is some voltage getting to the relay. If there is, it might have failed. Possibly, you can short it out as a test - how to do that will depend on the bike, which I know nothing about.